# Complex sort of chains in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "num": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    "name": [
        "281.3891.3891.281",
        "3891.281.281.3891",
        "1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1162",
        "5645.500835.500835.1162.1162.5645",
        "500835.1162.1162.5645.5645.500835",
        "1349.1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1349",
        "1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1349.1349.1162",
        "5645.500835.500835.1349.1349.1162.1162.5645",
        "500835.1349.1349.1162.1162.5645.5645.500835",
        "5645.1162.1162.500835.500835.5645",
        "1162.500835.500835.5645.5645.1162",
        "500835.5645.5645.1162.1162.500835",
    ],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Each line in dataframe is a chain (start point = end point).
But chains are not unique. (A-B-C-A = B-C-A-B = C-A-B-C <> B-A-C-B)
I can’t catch using which methods in Python I have to sort(using parallel shift) units of all chains to drop duplicates.

Comment: Having a hard time following your description. How come `A-B-C-A = B-C-A-B`? The first one has 2 As, the second one has 2 Bs.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what your actual question is?

Comment: @CodeDifferent 
I say "A-B-C-A = B-C-A-B"  because we have a chain - closed sequence of elements. These 2 sequences differs only with the starting point - the sequence is the same. Conserning my dataframe rows 3-4-5 is one chain, rows 10-11-12 is another chain. I am sorry that I did not provide the information sufficiently detailed at start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relational algebra aspect of your problem is minimal, so let's start with sorting the chains. You want to find an extrema, then rotate the chain until that extrema is in a known relative location with respect to the rest of the chain.

Let's use the first lowest value we find in the chain, and then rotate the chain until there are no larger values to its right. We'll wrap this in a UDF, so that we can use the output to create a new pandas column. We'll use the python `deque`, because it has a nice `rotate` API.

```
from collections import deque


def sort_chain(row):
    chain = deque(row['name'].split('.')) # deque(['281', '3891', '3891', '281'])
    anchor = min(chain) # 281
    chain.rotate(-chain.index(anchor)) # deque(['281', '3891', '3891', '281'])
    anchor_index = 0                   #         ^

    # Now we rotate to the right until there's no smaller value to the right
    while min(list(chain)[anchor_index + 1:]) <= anchor:
        chain.rotate(1)     # deque(['281', '281', '3891', '3891'])
        anchor_index += 1   #                ^
        # Don't forget to wrap the index around to the left side
        if anchor_index + 1 >= len(chain):
            anchor_index = 0

    return '.'.join(chain) # '281.281.3891.3891'
```

We apply the UDF to make a new column:

```
df['sorted_chain'] = df.apply(sort_chain, axis=1)
```

Which gives us this:

```
0                               281.281.3891.3891
1                               281.281.3891.3891
2               1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835
3               1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835
4               1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835
5     1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1349.1349
6     1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1349.1349
7     1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1349.1349
8     1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1349.1349
9               1162.1162.500835.500835.5645.5645
10              1162.1162.500835.500835.5645.5645
11              1162.1162.500835.500835.5645.5645
```

Now it's just a matter of dropping the dupes:

```
df.drop_duplicates('sorted_chain')

0                            281.3891.3891.281
2            1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1162
5  1349.1162.1162.5645.5645.500835.500835.1349
9            5645.1162.1162.500835.500835.5645
```